# How can i make three html audio elements work sequentially repeated using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i make three HTML audio elements work sequentially repeated each one three times or more.

means I will make the first audio work three times, then the second work three times, then the third three times

I have this code, but i don't have an idea to make the audio elements repeated:

HTML & JavaScript:

```js
function play(j){
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+j); //declaring audio
  audio.play();                                 //playing audio
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){  //after audio ends, it will check weather it will play again or no 
        j++;
if(j<=3){
        play(j);
   }
}) 
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="audio1">
   <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/jazz.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
   your browser doesn't support audio
  </audio><br/>
<audio controls id="audio2">
   <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/jazz.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
   your browser doesn't support audio
 </audio><br/>
<audio controls id="audio3">
   <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/jazz.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
   your browser doesn't support audio
  </audio>
  <button onclick="play(1)">run audio</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function play(j){
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+Math.floor(j)); //declaring audio
  audio.play();                                 //playing audio
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){  //after audio ends, it will check weather it will play again or no 
     j+=1/3;
     if(j<=3){
       play(j);
     }
   })   
 }
```

Simply just increase by a third (and round the number if you use it), so that it plays three times...

Or more beautiful (using an double-recursive approach ;)):

```
function playthree(i){
  (function play(c){
     var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+i); //declaring audio
     audio.play();                                 //playing audio
     audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){  //after audio ends, it will check weather it will play again or no 
        if(c>=3 ){//if more than three per audio
            if(i<3){//and not reached the last audio
              playthree(i+1);//play next audio
            }//else end all
        }else{//we didnt reached the third play, lets keep going...
         play(c+1);  
        }
     });
  })(1)//start with 1
}
```

Comment: Really thank you for the great solution,  especially the second one, I use it but I need to make a stop to the previous audio because it was work the old and the new audio, then all the old audios and the new one, I don't know why? but in end it is work fine.  Thank you